# When switched on a ground fault outlet cuts when reset it holds

Tags: electrical

When light is turned on by switch outlet trips, but when reset it holds.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you have a GFCI outlet which is controlled by a switch?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. As @brhans says, more information would help us help you. Please edit the information into the question.

Comment: Is the GFCI feeding the light and switch, or do you have a GFCI that has a switch controlling it? Also, what make/model (or vintage even) is the GFCI?

Comment: Some GFCI's have a safety that trips as you are experiencing the model # would help.